# Set the hashtag for a twitter timeline widget in php?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

Id like to have the twitter timeline widget https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines display tweets that are related to my a page, for example if I had a page on cats Id like it ti display a timeline that looks up #cats, or a page for dogs that looks up #dogs.

The only way I can see to do this is to create a different widget for each page which in my case would be impractical. Is there any way to simply have a timeline widget that will display what ever hash tag is passed into it by php when the page is loaded?